# IE 9 shows null

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my model I defined NullDisplayFormat

```
[StringLength(100)]
[DisplayName("First Contact")]
[DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "")]
[Column("Contact1",TypeName =  "varchar")]
public virtual string Contact1 { get; set; }
```

In Google Chrome and in FireFox I see nothing in the grid and input controls in my view. However, in IE 9 I see NULL. Is it a bug in IE 9? What is the simplest way to fix it?

I also tried to change null to nothing this way in jQuery:

```
var Contact1 = $('.trSelected td:eq(3)').text();
$('#Contact1').val(Contact1||'Nothing');
```

However, it didn't work since the Contact1 is already a string property = null. Do you know how can I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with display in the grid using JSON. So, I revised the code I return, e.g.

```
 var flexgrid = new
            {
                page = page,
                total = Total,
                rows = clients
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    id = x.Id,

                    cell = new { Id = x.Id, Number = x.Number, Name = x.Name, Contact1 = x.Contact1.Contact ?? String.Empty }
                }
                )
            };

            return Json(flexgrid, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Perhaps DisplayFormat only works for the viewing /editing this in a single control, not when we return it as a set. Interestingly Google Chrome and FireFox show NULL as empty string, though.